# channel-adapter's 'id' attribute is required when no 'channel' reference has been provided, because that 'id' would be used for the created channel

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I'm using spring-integration-kafka 1.1.2 version and facing this error, I cannot define id because it doesnt allow me to, please help.

Have added this code with a spring integration listener custom implementation

<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
listener-container="listenerContainer"/>

Was expecting everything to work fine but alas.
Spring integration version - 3.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those versions are very old and out of support. Consider to upgrade to the latest Spring Integration instead of trying to figure out what is wrong with whatever is not going to be supported: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn